# Is Virtual Memory in some way related to Virtualization Technology?

Tags: operating-system, virtualization

I think it is a bit vague question. But I was trying to get a clear understanding on how a hypervisor interacts with operating systems under the hood, and what makes them two so different. Let me just drive you through my thought process.

Why do we need a virtualization manager a.k.a. a hypervisor, if we already have an operating system to manage resources which are shared?

One answer that I got was: suppose the system crashes, and if we have no virtualization manager, then it's a full loss. So, virtualization keeps  another system unaffected, by providing isolation.

Okay, then why do we need an operating system? Well, both operating systems and hypervisors have different task to handle: hypervisor handles how to allocate the resources (compute, networking etc.), while OS handles process management, file system, memory (hmm.. We also have a virtual memory. Right?)

I think I haven't asked the question in a trivial manner? But I am confused, so may be I could get a little help to clear my insight.

Answer (score 2):

"Virtual" roughly means "something that is not what it seems". It is a common task in computing to substitute one thing with another.

A "virtual resource" is a common approach for that. It also means that there is an entity in a system that transparently substitutes one portion of resource with another. Memory is one of the most important resources in computing systems, therefore "Virtual Memory" is one of the first terms that historically was introduced.

However, there are other resources that are worth virtualizing. One can virtualize registers, or, more specifically, their values. Input/output devices, time, number of processors, network connections — all these resources can be and are virtualized these days (see: Intel VT-d, Virtual Time papers, Multicore simulators, Virtual switches and network adapters as respective examples). A combination of such things is what roughly constitutes a "Virtualization Technology". It is not a well-defined term, unless you talk about Intel® Virtualization Technology, which is one-vendor trade name.

In this sense, a hypervisor is such an entity that substitutes/manages chosen resources *transparently* to other controlled entities, which are then said to reside inside "containers", "jails", "virtual machines" — different names exist.

> Both operating system and hypervisors have different task to handle

In fact, they don't.

1. An operating system is just a hypervisor for regular user applications, as it manages resources behind their back and transparently for them. The resources are: virtual memory, because an OS makes it seem that every application has a huge flat memory space for its own needs; virtual time, because each application does not manage context switching points; virtual I/O, because each application uses system calls to access devices instead of directly writing into their registers.
2. A hypervisor is a fancy way to say a "second level operating system", as it virtualizes resources visible to operating systems. The resources are essentially the same: memory, time, I/O; a new thing are system registers.
3. It can go on and on, i.e. you can have hypervisors of higher levels that virtualize certain resources for entities of lower level. For Intel systems, it roughly corresponds to the stack SMM -> VMM -> OS -> user application, where SMM (system management mode) is the outermost hypervisor and user application is the inner entity (that actually does useful job of running a web browser and web server you use right now).

> Why do we need a virtualization manager aka hypervisor, if we already have an operating system to manage how the resources are shared?

We don't need it if chosen computer architecture supports more than one level of indirection for resource management (e.g. nested virtualization). Thus, it depends on chosen architecture. On certain IBM systems (System/360, years 1960-1970), hypervisors were invented and used much earlier than operating systems had been introduced in a modern sense. More common IBM Personal Computer architecture based on Intel x86 CPUs (around 1975) had deficiencies that did not allow to achieve required level of isolation between multiple OSes without introducing a second layer of abstraction (hypervisors) into the architecture (which happened around 2005).

Comment: Thanks for giving right direction to my thought process. But I have another doubt. What is the alternative of system calls in hypervisor, for accessing those cpu registers. Is it directly accessed?

Comment: @GopiShankar system calls are not used to access CPU registers. Peripheral device registers, maybe, but rarely CPU's. System calls represent a more general API for user applications to *explicitly* call an OS for a certain service. An equivalent of system calls in the relation "hypervisor—guest OS" is, surprisingly, *hypercalls*. They are used when a guest OS needs to *explicitly* request a service from a hypervisor. Note that a lot of work that OSes/hypervisors do consists of *implicit* services, such as on-demand paging, context switching, device spooling, interrupt routing etc.